# "Add-UnifiedGroupLinks is not recognized.." even though ExchangeOnlineManagement 2.0.5 is definitely installed

Tags: powershell, microsoft365

I'm semi-new to PowerShell, so please excuse if I mix up some terminology. I need to manage M365-Groups via PS. I've inherited a productive machine which had a very old ExchangeOnlineModule installed (v. 0.4578.0). This version did allowed me to **read** the M365-Group members via `get-unifiedGroupLinks -identity "zzz.test" -LinkType Members`, but not to **add** members.

Next installed the latest productive version of the **ExchangeOnlineMangement** module according to MS' manual.
The command

```
Get-InstalledModule
```

shows me version 2.0.5.
The command

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

shows both old an new version, installed in "*Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules*"

When I now try to run the following Add-command, I receive the error below:

```
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity "zzz.test" -LinkType Members -Links "mytestuser@mydomain.com"
```

```
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks : The term 'Add-UnifiedGroupLinks' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity "zzz.test" -LinkType Members -Link ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-UnifiedGroupLinks:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Same after I "manually" import that specific module version with "Import-Module".

Can anyone help me understand why this command works on my test machine, but is simply not recognized on this one? I already restarted that productive machine after the installation.

Thank you in advance & best regards

MK

Comment: Does it still show running `Get-Module` by itself?

Comment: Good point - yes, it shows (with correct version 2.0.5) as one of 7 entries when I run ```Get-Module``` by itself

Comment: Did you connect to Exchange Online beforehand?

Comment: Yessir, connected. The Get-UnifiedGroupLinks command does still work after the Module update. When I try the Add-command right after that - no joy.

Comment: Okay, last questions. Are you using an Exchange Management Shell? Can you show me how you connected to exchange?

Comment: No, I'm using the regular ISE, connecting with ```Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName "myadmin@mydomain.com"```. I'll be using the Add-commands in an Azure runbook later down the line.

Comment: That is the issue. You have you use an Exchange Shell, or a session connected to exchange.

Comment: I am having a session connected to Exchange, as I can read out group memberships. However, some testing today showed, that it most likely has to do with insufficient access rights. As "Global administrator" role I can read and write to M365-Groups, as "Groups administrator" role I receive the misleading "cmd not found" error, when trying to write.

Comment: According to [ExchangePowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps), you need an Exchange Shell, or using a PSSession; see note on that link.

Comment: I was refering to the ExchangeOnlineManagement, aka "Exchange Online Powershell V2  Module", mentioned in the same note. The rest of the note talks about onprem Exchange, as far as I understand. However, I found the cause in insufficient access rights

Answer (score 1):

Figured it with testing: The issue was **insufficient access rights** in AzureAD for the user used to connect to Exchange Online.

It would seem that the module only loads the commands for which you have the access rights to use into the connected session. Therefor, when you try to use such a command (like `Add-UnifiedGroupLins`) you get a "**Term is not recognized**" error, instead of something meaningfull.

For those who care: It worked for me after adding the **Exchange administrator** role and, obviously, with the **Global administrator** role. Maybe there is a lesser role that is sufficient, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Glad you got it working